# cannot convert value of type UIImage to expected argument type string

Tags: swift, xcode, sprite-kit, swift2, xcode8

I have some problem with swift.

```
Ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "#imageLiteral(resourceName: "Ground")")
```

Here it says "cannot convert value of type UIImage to expected argument type string" how can i fix this

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe I'm missing something but why are you adding this?

```
#imageLiteral(resourceName:
```

The correct syntax is

```
let ground = SKSpriteNode(imageNamed: "Ground")
```

Comment: I'm trying to get the "Ground" picture on the bottom of the screen when i do 'let' or 'string' it tells me to add a `;` and no matter how many i type it always wants one more. That code is inside 
`override func didMove(to view: SKView)` and i got a 
`var Ground = SKSpriteNode()` inside `class GameScene: SKScene {`
All i did was start a Game project in Xcode and i only wrote that so far.

Comment: So i was selecting the img when i used that line of code i copied yours next to mine and the only difference was that yours wasn't selecting any img thank you fixed the problem

Answer (score 2):

I was doing :

```
profileImgView.image = UIImage(named: #imageLiteral(resourceName: "default_UserImage"))
```

while it should be :

```
profileImgView.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "default_UserImage")
```

## imageLiteral already return UIImage.